# Type hinting of dependency injection

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I'm creating a declarative http client and have a problem with mypy linting.

Error:

```
Incompatible default for argument "user" (default has type "Json", argument has type "dict\[Any, Any\]")
```

I have a "Dependency" class that implements the logic of: value validation agains type, request modification:

```
class Dependency(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(
        self,
        default: Any = Empty,
        field_name: Union[str, None] = None,
    ):
        self.default = default
        self._overridden_field_name = field_name

    ...

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def modify_request(self, request: RawRequest) -> RawRequest:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

The dependencies inherited from `Dependency`, e.g. Json:

```
class Json(Dependency):
    location = Location.json

    def __init__(self, default: Any = Empty):
        """Field name is unused for Json."""
        super().__init__(default=default)

    def modify_request(self, request: "RawRequest") -> "RawRequest":
        ...
        return request
```

Then I use them as function argument's default to declare:

```
@http("GET", "/example")
def test_get(data: dict = Json()):
    ...
```

It works as expected, but mypy is raising a lot of errors.

The question - how to deal with type hinting?

I need it to work like Query() or Body() in FastAPI, without changing the way of declaration.

I tried to make a Dependency class to be generic, but it wasn't helped me.

UPD:

Sorry, forgot to mention that type hint can be dataclass, or pydantic model, or any other type. Then it will be deserialized in function execution.

Dict as type annotation:

```
@http("GET", "/example")
def test_get(data: dict = Json()):
    ...
```

Pydantic model as type annotation:

```
class PydanticModel(BaseModel):
   …

@http("GET", "/example")
def test_get(data: PydanticModel = Json()):
    ...
```

Dataclass as type annotation:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class DataclassModel():
   …


@http("GET", "/example")
def test_get(data: DataclassModel = Json()):
    ...
```

It should support any type provided in type hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using [`typing.Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated), declaration has been changed a bit, but it works correctly and mypy has no errors to show.

```
@http("GET", "/example")
def test_get(data: Annotated[DataclassModel, Json()]):
    ...
```

Then I'm using a function signature to extract dependency, type hint and do magic...

```
def extract_dependencies(func: Callable):
    signature = inspect.signature(func)
    for key, val in signature.parameters.items():
        if key in ["self", "cls"]:
            # We don't need the self or cls parameter.
            continue

        # We check if the parameter is annotated.
        annotation = func.__annotations__.get(key, None)
        if hasattr(annotation, "__metadata__"):
            # Extracting the type hint and the dependency from the
            # Annotated type.
            type_hint, dependency = get_args(annotation)
            if not isinstance(dependency, Dependency):
                if inspect.isclass(dependency) and issubclass(
                    dependency, Dependency
                ):
                    # If the dependency is a class, we instantiate it.
                    dependency = dependency()
                    dependency.type_hint = type_hint
                else:
                    # If the dependency is not an instance of Dependency,
                    # we raise an AnnotationException.
                    raise AnnotationException(annotation)
            else:
                # If the dependency is already an instance of Dependency,
                # we are setting only the type hint.
                dependency.type_hint = type_hint
        else:
            ...
        dependency.field_name = key
        dependency.value = values.get(key, val.default)
        yield dependency
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're encountering is due to the type hint not matching the default value's type. The function `test_get` expects a parameter data of type `dict`, but the default value you provided is of type Json, which is a subclass of Dependency.

See here: `class Json(Dependency):`

You need to make sure your `Json` class can act as a dict, you can do this by inheriting from dict in addition to `Dependency`

```
class Json(Dependency, dict):
    location = Location.json

    def __init__(self, default: Any = Empty):
        """Field name is unused for Json."""
        super().__init__(default=default)

    def modify_request(self, request: "RawRequest") -> "RawRequest":
        ...
        return request
```

You could also implement all the dict emulation methods yourself, but this is a little more involved.

Comment: Nice solution, thank you very much! I just forgot to mention, that type hint can be dataclass or pydantic model…

Comment: If this answered your question, you can mark it as accepted. If not, i think i need more clarification

Comment: It is answering the question, but not for 100%. I added more details in the question. Thank you for replies.